# Mysqli select from from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have data stored in two different tables called "posts" and "comments".
Now i'm using two mysqli_query.

```
    $q = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE username='$username'");
    $q = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM comments WHERE username='$username'");
```

Can I make this with only one mysqli_query or with 3 tables?

Comment: Are you just looking for the `JOIN` keyword?  Also, that looks like a SQL injection vulnerability you have there.

Comment: Show us db schema and expected result. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply join both tables:

```
$q = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.username=posts.username 
WHERE comments.username='$username'");
```

However, it looks like you are not using IDs. I suggest you to create ID auto-increment fields to make the relationship between tables. If you don't understand what I mean, try to follow a tutorial and in an our or two you would have learned more, than just by jumping into coding trying to do things and trying to understand how they work without even knowing if you are doing it right.

Comment: left join with `where` over same table becomes inner join :) however left join is not necessary here, inner join is the proper join in that case.

Comment: @mitkosoft, true about the joins. (I was to fast to respond :)
 With the information that he shared we can't do much on advising the best way to do it. I just wanted to show it done with one query, but my main objective was to suggest him to learn a little more about DBs & SQL, as there's no point on building great queries if the DB tables, fields and relationships are not well structured.