# Mysqli PHP prepared statement when the query uses SQL variable

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I wanted to make my SQL query into a prepared statement but realized, that it wasn't as easy as I first thought. Here is the query in its current form, so not as prepared statement.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(...);

$result = mysqli_query( $mysqli,
"SELECT count(*) as total from test_users, image_uploads 
    WHERE test_users.APPROVAL = 'granted'
    AND test_users.NAME = image_uploads.OWNER
    AND (test_users.IMGAUTO = 'enabled' OR image_uploads.IAPPROVAL = 'granted')
");
$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result );
$row_cnt = $data['total'];
$totalPages = ceil(($row_cnt / $cardmax));
```

So my problem now is this. When I make the prepared statement, I'm not going to  be able to access `image_uploads.OWNER` anymore since I use it inside the query at the moment.

```
$grant = 'granted';
$owner = ""; //<<--- how to get image_uploads.OWNER
$enabl = 'enabled';

$sql = 
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test_users, image_uploads
    WHERE test_users.APPROVAL=?
    AND test_users.NAME=?
    AND (test_users.IMGAUTO=? OR image_uploads.IAPPROVAL=?)
";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $grant, $owner, $enabl, $grant);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_row();
$row_cnt = $row[0];
$totalPages = ceil(($row_cnt / $cardmax));
```

Is there a method to get this `image_uploads.OWNER` in my prepared statement. How do I do this correctly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575695/mysqli-select-from-from-two-tables

Comment: @CrandellWS no, you've entirely missed the point of the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `image_uploads.OWNER` is a column in a SQL table in your database. If so, then you can just leave it as it is in your first version. You don't need to parameterise it.

Only data values coming from outside the database engine (e.g. user input, or data from a file) need to be parameterised, because that data is potentially unknown and could contain malicious values / injection attacks which need to be sanitised against. Quoting a column name from another table cannot pose such a threat - you are not putting an unknown string value into the query syntax.

N.B. In actual fact none of your original query relies on external input or unknown variables - all of the data is hard-coded into the query text. So you don't actually need to parameterise anything at all in this particular query. Everything is set in advance, so there is no threat from surprise / unknown text becoming part of the executable SQL.

Comment: very helpful, thanks! ok, then I can just leave it as it is.. that's great! Thanks again for the insight, I will go through my code again and keep that in mind.